# On click, remove previously loaded html section

Tags: jquery, load

This should be very straight forward but for some reason it is not working as intended. I have a blog post with a read more button, when it is clicked a modal is shown covering the entire page (absolute positioned over the entire page).

On that modal there is a button to just remove the content, the modal itself.

```
    $('.blog-block .blog-entry-extra-tag').on('click', function(){
        console.log('clicked first read More');
        $( "#blog-modal" ).load("blog/blog-entry-1.html");
    });

    $(".close-blog-post button").on("click", function(){
        $( "#blog-modal" ).empty();
        console.log("clicked close button")
    });
```

The first click event works and it loads the content. The second click event does not work. If I enter the code in the console:

```
$( "#blog-modal" ).empty();
```

It does remove the content as I want it to. So why it doesn't work? I cannot see the console log either.

Comment: can you show the html of the second button?

Comment: It's just a div with a button, I have tried different things, it is a button and it shows the clicking animation so there's nothing over it preventing me from clicking it or anything.

Comment: To be able to help you, we need to see every part of the code involved in your issue.